# Difference between visible:false and hidden:true

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, puppeteer, browser-automation

What is the difference between `visible:false` and `hidden:true` for `page.waitForSelector`

I read puppeteer [page.waitForSelector](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options) documentation and [PR 967](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/pull/967)

I am not able to understand their usecases as well as most importantly difference between them.

```
await page.waitForSelector(selector, {visible:false});
```

and

```
await page.waitForSelector(selector, {hidden:true});
```

Can someone please put some light on it and explain with real life scenarios?

Comment: These CSS attributes do not exactly do the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Answer (score 1):

The options have simply a reverse boolean logic:

**hidden: true**

`display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS

**visible: false**

`display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS

Ref: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.19.0/docs/api.md#framewaitfornavigationoptions

Comment: Both is dispay:none or visibility:hidden CSS. So what is the difference?

Comment: The difference is in the boolean provided, one is falsy, the other is truthy. Output result are the same